# Full command text with unix ps

Tags: unix, shell

When we enter:

```
ps -f
```

... the CMD column text doesn't show the full command.  Any way to prevent this truncating?

Seems like it's showing the first 80 characters.  We are running a fairly log command that has lots of command line switches.

---

Thanks for the responses..  doesn't seem like any of these do the trick though..

Answer (score 81):

Pipe the result into `cat` .. that'll ignore your terminal settings.

```
ps -f | cat
```

Comment: I use `ps aux` before, now `ps aux | cat`, it's magic.

Answer (score 49):

I found this on my FreeBSD's 9 ps man page:

> -w      Use 132 columns to display information, instead of the default
> which is your window size.  **If the -w option is specified more
> than once, ps will use as many columns as necessary without
> regard for your window size**.  Note that this option has no effect
> if the “command” column is not the last column displayed.

So:

```
ps auxww
```

Did what I wanted.

Comment: Confused why this isn't the most popular answer.

Comment: +1 for not involving any other command. `ps -fww` (using UNIX options syntax) works too.

Answer (score 13):

If `/usr/ucb` dir exists then you may try following command

```
/usr/ucb/ps -auxww | grep java
```

Answer (score 12):

`ps` detects the size of your terminal window and clips to that.

Solution: don't output directly to the terminal!

```
ps -f | less
```

Answer (score 4):

`man ps`:

> -w Use 132 columns to display information, instead of the default
> which is your window size.  If the -w
> option is specified more than once, ps
> will use as many columns as necessary
> without regard for your window size.
> When output is not to a terminal, an
> unlimited number of columns are always
> used.

Hence:

```
ps -f | cat
```

Works.

Answer (score 2):

`more` works perfectly for me

```bash
ps -ef |more
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't forget that `-eaf` works with normal `ps` only and not luddite ucb `ps`.

Ucb `ps` uses multiple `-w` options to give you the complete command line.

Answer (score 1):

As other answers have noted, piping the output to another command (e.g., `less` or `more`) or redirecting to a file will usually result in the terminal width being ignored.

However, if that's not working, it might be because the [`COLUMNS`](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bash-Variables.html#index-COLUMNS) shell variable is being exported into your environment, in which case `ps` will use that value as the terminal width ([ref](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/ps.1.html#ENVIRONMENT_VARIABLES)).

To fix that issue, you can unexport (`export -n COLUMNS`) or unset (`unset COLUMNS`) the variable, or pass one of the `--cols <n>`, `--columns <n>`, or `--width <n>` options -- these are all [synonyms](https://gitlab.com/procps-ng/procps/-/blob/3aa2a49f0e066e3342599e20316b41ede22cce50/src/ps/parser.c#L880-882) in the procps-ng implementation of `ps` that's most commonly used on Linux.